# Access Windows Phone Device by Folder Picker

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, uwp

I'm looking for a method to access my windows phone folder (plugged per usb) from a Desktop Windows App. To get full write and read rights I thought it would be the best way to use a folder picker.

The folder picker works fine, but there is a big problem. The windows phone device isnt listed in the folder picker contrary to the normal windows explorer. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Here is my code for the folder picker:

```js
            FolderPicker selectWpFolder = new FolderPicker();
            selectWpFolder.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
            selectWpFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            selectWpFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");

            wpMusik = await selectWpFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            if (wpMusik != null) {
              StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", wpMusik);
            }
```

Comment: You may have to declare the **removableStorage** capability in your app manifest. Also have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx) and  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188699.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile phone is connected as a portable device, not as a disk drive. Hence you are unable to see it in folder picker.

Use [Storage Device Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.portable.storagedevice.aspx) to access connected devices.